# selecting multiple times same foreign key in sql

Tags: sql

I have table `foo` with columns:

```
fid, lat, long
1, 0.1, 0.11
2, 0.2, 0.22
3, 0.3, 0.33
4, 0.4, 0.44
```

and table `bar`:

```
bid, f1, f2, f3
1, 1, 2, 3
2, 4, 3, 1
```

I want to get the `lat`,`long` of `f1`,`f2`,`f3` for every entry of `bar` table.

So far I have created the query:

```
select
  b.bid,
  f1.lat, f1.long,
  f2.lat, f2.long,
  f3.lat, f3.long
from
  bar as b,
  foo as f1,
  foo as f2,
  foo as f3
where
  b.f1=f1.fid and
  b.f2=f2.fid and
  b.f3=f3.fid;

bid, lat, long, lat, "long", "lat", "long"
1, 0.1, 0.11, 0.2, 0.22, 0.3, 0.33
2, 0.4, 0.44, 0.3, 0.33, 0.1, 0.11
```

The `foo.fid` and `bar.bid` are primary keys. Also I can add any index needed to the tables.

Is there any faster more efficient query to get the same result?

Comment: Do you have indexes/keys?

Comment: Sorry @jarlh, I forgot it. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Don’t do old-style joins, do explicit joins.

```
select
  b.bid,
  f1.lat, f1.long,
  f2.lat, f2.long,
  f3.lat, f3.long
from
  bar as b left join foo as f1 on b.f1 = f1.fid
  left join  foo as f2 on b.f2 = f2.fid
  left join  foo as f3 on b.f3 = f3.fid
```

Assuming, of course, that bid and fid are a primary-foreign key pair.

If you have a huge table or it is a very performance-sensitive scenario you should add an index to your tables on the keys. If you are guaranteed values in foo for every tuple of ( f1, f2, f3 ) you could use an inner join instead.

Comment: Thanks! Why is this faster?

Comment: In my experience the best performance comes from explicit inner joins. A left join does an inner join first and then pads out any missing values with null extensions, so it will at best be exactly as fast as an inner join Really you get the bang for your buck by adding indexes to the keys. However, only use the inner join if you're sure that will give you the data you want.